# Does the main kernel "make" command also make modules internally?

Tags: module, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am learning how to write kernel drivers and this is my first attempt to build one. I have created a folder `drivers/naveen/` for my module files - `hello.c`,`Kconfig` and `Makefile`. These are the contents of these files :

Kconfig

```
config HELLO_WORLD
        tristate "Hello World support"
        default m
        ---help---
          This option enables printing hello world
```

Makefile

```
obj-$(CONFIG_HELLO_WORLD) += hello.o
```

hello.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ERR "This is NAVEEN module");
    return 0;
}

static int __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ERR "NAVEEN exiting module");
    return 0;
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
MODULE_AUTHOR("Naveen");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Also, I have added the following line in `drivers/Makefile` :

```
obj-$(CONFIG_HELLO_WORLD)       += naveen/
```

and the following line in `drivers/Kconfig` :

```
source "drivers/naveen/Kconfig"
```

My generated `.config` contains `CONFIG_HELLO_WORLD=m`.

I did `make ARCH=x86_64 -j16` and I can see `hello.ko` generated. Why? I was expecting to get it generated only when I had done `make modules` as its set to be as modular with `m` inside the `.config`, and not to be compiled with just make. Can someone please explain the behaviour to me or what wrong I am doing?

Does that mean that `make` also does `make modules`. I can see from `make help` that `make` actually means `make all` and hence it should do `make modules` as well internally, and so there should be no need to do `make modules` once make is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux kernel consists of 2 parts - core kernel and modules. When we do simply `make`, it means `make all` which means `make vmlinux && make modules`. Hence, if we have done `make`, we need not do `make modules` again and we can simply run the command `make modules_install` without doing `make modules`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong. The `modules` target has been a dependency of the `all` target since kernel version 2.6.0 (actually since kernel version 2.5.60 I think).

The way you are adding your module is to add it to the kernel source tree. It is also possible to build custom modules outside the kernel source tree - so called "out-of-tree" kernel modules. Typically, those don't need a Kconfig file and the `obj-$(CONFIG_HELLO_WORLD)` would be replaced with `obj-m` in the Makefile.

Here is a Makefile for an "out-of-tree" version of your "hello" module:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
# Kbuild part of Makefile

obj-m += hello.o

else
# Normal part of Makefile
#

# Kernel build directory specified by KDIR variable
# Default to running kernel's build directory if KDIR not set externally
KDIR ?= "/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build"

all:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(KDIR)" M=`pwd` modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(KDIR)" M=`pwd` clean

endif
```

This Makefile uses a common trick so that the same Makefile can be invoked as a "normal" Makefile and as a "kbuild" Makefile.  The "normal" part between the `else` and `endif` lines invokes `$(MAKE)` on the kernel's Makefile (the location of which is specified by the `KDIR` variable), telling it to build the `modules` target in the current directory (specified by `` M=`pwd` ``). The "kbuild" part is between the `ifneq($(KERNELRELEASE),)` and `else` lines and is in the normal "kbuild" format for building parts of the kernel.

That trick depends on the `KERNELRELEASE` variable being initially unset or empty. It will be set to a non-empty value by the kernel's Makefile rules.